# Which is best method to post delay when send message to Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, java-threads

I want to send five data to Bluetooth. First one is turn on and second one is turn off, third one is turn on, and so on... I want post delay between turn on and turn off (about 1 second). Which is best one to do it. Currently, I am using sleep in Thread class

```
   for (int i=1;i<5;i++) {
            try {
                if(i%2==0){
                    send(1);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                else{          
                    send(0);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```